# .NET / CSS Foreach Checkboxes Individual Styling

Tags: c#, css, razor

I have a `foreach` loop creating `CheckBox`es, causing them to all have the same ID. I've got some CSS but when you check any box it puts the css onto the first iteration, how do I add some dynamic ID sort of thing to only add the css to the selected box?

Loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(p => p.UserTable.ID == ViewBag.UserTableID))
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="select">
                <input type="checkbox" id="select" name="" />
                <label for="select"></label>
            </div>
```

css:

```
.select {
width: 20px;
position: relative;
}

.select label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

    .select label:after {
        opacity: 0.2;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 9px;
        height: 5.5px;
        background: transparent;
        top: 4.8px;
        left: 5.4px;
        border: 3px solid #333;
        border-top: none;
        border-right: none;
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

.select label:hover::after {
opacity: 0.5;
}

.select input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: You can simply use your `item.UserTable.ID` if it has more than one ID to create dynamic IDs and the input class can be `class="select"`, this way you can apply the same CSS to every checkbox and have different IDs. Another way is to use the element index in the array or something in your object that makes it unique.

Comment: ids should be unique so you've got to fix that anyway (you could use an incremented counter).  But for the css, you could use something like nth-child

Comment: @ThadeuFernandes by the looks of the linq query, that id would be the same for each item

Comment: @Pete yeah, I noticed after my comment. Just added another way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just assign each element their item's ID?

```
<div class="select">
    <input type="checkbox" id="select_@item.ID" />
    <label for="select"></label>
</div>
```

Unless you have duplicates in that list, they'll always be unique.

By the way: your View shouldn't be filtering out items, it should be given only the items it needs (that `Where` should be done at the database level)

Comment: It probably has duplicates,I believe `ViewBag.UserTableID` is not an array and it create multiple checkboxes with only one ID.

Comment: @ThadeuFernandes That's for `item.UserTable.ID`, I suggested `item.ID` which should not have anything to do with the `UserTable` relationship

Comment: Yeah I assumed I could do this but then how would the CSS know which one to style for selection? would this be using JS? sorry if I sound like an idiot! Ahh yeah noted, have been moving out any linq expressions from views just an old one.

Comment: @liamcook That would depend on how each item should be styled. You could either use `@if` to specify the classes at the server, use CSS selectors (like `2n-1`) in your CSS or use JavaScript at the document ready event. Notice that in the CSS you posted you never use IDs